# Identifying the EPSG code for projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, epsg, pyproj, mercator

I'm trying to convert a dataset that has projection parameters in meters to lat/long coordinates. After researching online and on stack exchange, I came up with a code. I used the input EPSG as 3857 and the output EPSG as 4326. But unfortunately, the resulting files do not match the output visualized in the Panoply software.

Is there anyone who has worked on similar datasets? Am I giving the input EPSG code wrong? Attaching some screenshots and the file metadata for reference.

In panoply software, the data is getting correctly visualized but I'm not unable to convert its lat/long for plotting purposes.

The file can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xQHNgrlrbyNcb6UyV36xh-7zTfg3f8OQ/view?usp=share_link

I used the following code to convert it:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyproj import Proj, transform


# read coordinates in a dataframe
df_y = pd.DataFrame(np.array(h5py.File("mer.h5")['Y']))
df_x = pd.DataFrame(np.array(h5py.File("mer.h5")['X']))

# combine dataframes
df_comb = pd.concat([df_x,df_y], ignore_index=True, sort=False, axis=1)

# name columns
df_comb.set_axis(['X1','Y1'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# convert coordinates to degree
#cordinates = pd.read_csv('Y.csv')
df_comb['X2'] = ''
df_comb['Y2'] = ''

def convert(x1,y1,i):
    inProj = Proj('epsg:3857')
    outProj = Proj('epsg:4326')
    x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1,always_xy=True)
    df_comb.loc[i,'X2'] = x2
    df_comb.loc[i,'Y2'] = y2
    return(x2,y2)

for i in range(len(df_comb))[:2]:
    x1=df_comb.loc[i,'X1'] 
    y1=df_comb.loc[i,'Y1'] 
    convert(x1, y1, i)
```

[image: Visualization in Panoply]

[image: Wrong visualization coming used the code]

Meta information shows the following information:

```
Datum = "WGS84"; 
:Ellipsoid = "WGS84"; 
:conventions = "CF-1.6"; 
:upper_left_xy(meters) = -3234623.003937, 5401854.420193; 
:grid_mapping_name = "mercator"; 
:false_easting = 0.0; 
:false_northing = 0.0; 
:longitude_of_projection_origin = 75.0; 
:semi_major_axis = 6378137.0; 
:semi_minor_axis = 6356752.3142; 
:standard_parallel = 17.75;
```

Comment: you could try looking on epsg.io for a matching projection

Comment: Where did you get the data? That will typically have something that explains it. It doesn't look like anything common, and you may need to write a custom proj string.

Comment: @BradHards Got it from MOSDAC site of Indian space research organization. They do not have any information related to the projection. I'm wondering how the Panoply software is able to visualize it.

Comment: @IanTurton How do I do it? I know that the output should be in EPSG format, but not sure about the input epsg code of the projection.

Comment: What does `ogrinfo` show? Can you provide a link to download the source file?

Comment: @BradHards : Here's the link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xQHNgrlrbyNcb6UyV36xh-7zTfg3f8OQ/view?usp=share_link

I don't know how to read ogr info

Comment: @BradHards should that be `gdalinfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I was able to figure it out.

The projection information can be obtained from the H5 file itself. Please find the attached code for reference:

```
    with h5py.File("mer.h5", "r") as file:
    df_X = pd.DataFrame(file.get("X")[:-2], columns=["X"])
    df_Y = pd.DataFrame(file.get("Y"), columns=["Y"])
    DHI = file.get("DHI")[0][:, :-2].reshape(-1)
    projection= file['Projection_Information']
    lat_0= float(projection.attrs['standard_parallel'])
    lon_0= float(projection.attrs['longitude_of_projection_origin'])
    

final = df_Y.merge(df_X, how="cross").assign(DHI=DHI)[["X", "Y", "DHI"]]


projString='+proj=merc +lat_ts='+str(lat_0)+' +lon_0='+str(lon_0)
inProj=Proj(projString)
outProj=Proj(init='epsg:4326')


final['X2'],final['Y2']=transform(inProj,outProj,final[["X"]].to_numpy(),final[["Y"]].to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided the input EPSG is truly 3857, this should be a case of:

```
myProj = Proj(epsg)
X, Y = myProj(lon, lat)
```

However, I think it is important to understand a bit more about EPSG:3857. This would be a somewhat strange projection for this file to be in. Typically, this is a projection only used by Google Maps, Bing, Open street map. I think you should start by confirming this.

More generally, you can speed up your code a lot here. H5 files are read natively as arrays and merging dataframes in this way is not particularly efficient. Proj will also take arrays so there's no need for a loop. An alternative solution would be:

```
def reproj(lon,lat,EPSG):

    myProj = Proj('epsg:3857')
```

X, Y = myProj(lon, lat)

```
    return X,Y

in_lat = h5py.File("mer.h5")['Y']
in_lon = h5py.File("mer.h5")['X']

out_lon, out_lat = reproj(in_lon, in_lat)


df = pd.DataFrame({"in_lat":in_lat, "in_lon":in_lon, "out_lat":out_lat, "out_lon":out_lon})
```

Note: on my phone and don't know why that line won't format properly

Comment: The problem is that i donot know the input EPSG. Is there anyway to know that

Comment: Ask the data supplier

Answer (score 2):

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs_cf.html

```py
from pyproj import CRS

cc = CRS.from_cf({ 
    "grid_mapping_name": "mercator",
    "false_easting": 0,
    "false_northing": 0,
    "longitude_of_projection_origin": 75,
    "semi_major_axis": 6378137,
    "semi_minor_axis": 6356752.3142,
    "standard_parallel": 17.75,
})
```

- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#proj-not-a-generic-latitude-longitude-to-projection-converter
- https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#upgrading-to-pyproj-2-from-pyproj-1
- https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1400

```py
from pyproj import Transformer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import h5py

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(cc, "EPSG:4326", always_xy=True)
x_coords = np.array(h5py.File("mer.h5")['X'])
y_coords = np.array(h5py.File("mer.h5")['Y'])
lon, lat = transformer.transform(x_coords, y_coords)

df = pd.DataFrame({"x_coords":x_coords, "y_coords":y_coords,"lon":lon, "lat":lat})
```

However, you are probably looking for rioxarray to re-project a grid:

- https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray
- https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject.html

Comment: I tried running your code, but the values received are not correct.

I've added the projection info as another comment below.

Comment: :upper_left_lat_lon(degrees) = 45.5, 44.5;
  :upper_right_lat_lon(degrees) = 45.5, 105.5; 
  :lower_left_lat_lon(degrees) = -10.0, 44.5; 
  :lower_right_lat_lon(degrees) = -10.0, 105.5; 
  :upper_left_xy(meters) = -3234623.003937, 5401854.420193; 
  :grid_mapping_name = "mercator";
  :false_easting = 0.0; 
  :false_northing = 0.0; 
  :longitude_of_projection_origin = 75.0;
  :semi_major_axis = 6378137.0;
  :semi_minor_axis = 6356752.3142; 
  :standard_parallel = 17.75; 
  :_FillValue = 664365180; 
  :_ChunkSizes = 1U;